# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I have recently wrapped my component in test with ThemeProvider. When I ran my tests it's throwing the following error

> 'Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead'

Before wrapping it was working fine. How can I resolve this issue? I found many issues similar to this in GitHub and I tried all those ways still I'm getting the same error.

The code before wrapping:

```
 test('handleSelect function called on option select', () => {
    const handleSelectSpy = sinon.spy();
    wrapper = mount( 
        <Dropdown handleSelect={handleSelectSpy} options={options} />
    );
    dropdown = wrapper.find('Dropdown');
    dropdown
      .find('InputBase')
      .find('[role="button"]')
      .simulate('click');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

code after wrapping:

```
 test('handleSelect function called on option select', () => {
    const handleSelectSpy = sinon.spy();
    wrapper = mount(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Dropdown handleSelect={handleSelectSpy} options={options} />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );
    dropdown = wrapper.find('Dropdown');
    dropdown
      .find('InputBase')
      .find('[role="button"]')
      .simulate('click');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Error:
Dropdown - Full DOM rendering › handleSelect function called on option select
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.find('InputBase')
```

if this is a component classname/constructor function it should be without quotes:

```
.find(InputBase)
```

Only CSS selector is expected to be used inside quotes.

Comment: In fact this is not exactly what the Enzyme API Reference says. Although [not recommended](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#1-a-valid-css-selector), a React component [may be searched by its display name](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#3-a-react-components-displayname), which is a string.

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** I also faced this issue when forgetting to import a component. Like, in this example, if I forget to import the `InputBase` component to my test file, and trying to find it by its constructor `.find(InputBase)`, when running the test Jest showed errors like this `Method "someFunction" is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead`. I've lost **some** minutes trying to figure out what was happening.