# react fabric dropdown unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to unit testing and trying to write test cases for checking the "text" dropdown options. 
my code:

```
const options = [
     {
        key: 'Select',
        text: 'value1',
     },
<Dropdown
   placeholder="dropdown value"
   options={options[0]}
   disabled={true}
   className="style"
   />
```

my test file is:

```
let wrapper = shallow(<App />)
it('selected option text', () => {

    const dropdown= shallow(<Dropdown options={options[0]} />)       
        const value= dropdown.find(Dropdown);

        expect(value.children()).toEqual('value1');
```

How can I pass the options text into children? or is there any better way to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921107/method-simulate-is-meant-to-be-run-on-1-node-0-found-instead)

Comment: full list of values expected: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html

Comment: so you are mixing two different approaches: displayName and CSS selector. The best long-term solution is providing some special attribute like `data-test-id` for picking one particular component by `find({ "data-test-id": "my-target-dropdown"})` or alike

Comment: I tried with component.find(Dropdown) but showing error as Dropdown is undefined. How can I add 'text' in  "my-target-dropdown" ? Can you please give me more information?

Comment: did you `import {Dropdown} from ... ` beforehand?

Comment: I updated my post and imported Dropdown correctly. How can i pass selector and string to children to get the option text?

Comment: so are not passing `value` but only `options`. and you can validate what `value.prop("options")` has.